# Why getByRole does not accept the "ul" as a string?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a `React app` with `React Testing Library`.
I try to get a `ul` element like this:

```js
const { render, getByRole } = require("@testing-library/react");
const { default: MoviesList } = require("../components/MoviesList");
const { default: MoviesProvider } = require("../utils/MoviesProvider");

describe("<MoviesList />", () => {
  it("Component should exist", () => {
    render(
      <MoviesProvider value={{}}>
        <MoviesList />
      </MoviesProvider>
    );


    const ul = getByRole('ul');

    expect(ul).toBeInTheDocument()

    // or
    expect(getByRole("ul"), isInTheDocument);

  });
});
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`ul` is an element, not an accessibility role.
The corresponding role is `list` :

```js
const ul = getByRole('list');
expect(ul).toBeInTheDocument()
```

You can find a list of existing roles here https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions

Comment: Well I thought all HTML elements were legit. Anyway, thanks for the link. The strange thing is, that it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was importing `getByRole` on the top from `@testing-library/react`. When I tried to import it from `render` it worked.

Can anyone explain why?

```js
const { getByRole } = render(
      <MoviesProvider value={{}}>
        <MoviesList />
      </MoviesProvider>
    );


    const list = getByRole('list');
```